# Location, lon lat, parsing with python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've got some lon lat points that are in a string format. Example data below.

[image]

Now, I want to use these and put them into two different lists, for lon and lat respectively.

However this data is all in a string format, within a single list structure. I think this means I need to use regex?

I've tried using this code as below,

```
re.sub("^(\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$"
,"",exampledatalatlon[1])
```

But i can't get it to work. Does anyone know a quick and easy way to just reformat it into integer format (int() won't work) given I've tried these methods already?

cheers

Comment: Can you please provide a text version of the image? That way it can be reproduced easily.

Comment: Could you also provide a before/after text description ? 
My first hunch would be to isolate the longitude/latitude as string values ( longitude: everything enclosed between "(" and ",", latitude : everything enclosed between "," and ")" ), then convert these strings to whatever numeric format you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
input_string = """
(150.32424, -234.4234242)
(242.42342, -42342.4242)
(-2424, 2424)
"""
result = re.findall(r"\((-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?), *(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)", input_string)

# Use this if you just want the integer parts
# result = re.findall(r"\((-?\d+)(?:\.\d+)?, *(-?\d+)(?:\.\d+)?\)", input_string)

long, lat =  zip(*map(lambda pair: map(float, pair), result))

print(long) 
(150.32424, 242.42342, -2424.0)

print(lat)
(-234.4234242, -42342.4242, 2424.0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware that you are trying to convert them to `int`'s and it shouldn't be that hard after this point. Just a simple `map` is enough but I'm trying to find a one-line solution. I'll let you now if I can. @MichaelHolborn

Comment: @MichaelHolborn I edited my answer. Hope it does what you want!

Answer (score 3):

```py
example = '(150.11, 33.20)'
lat, lon = map( lambda x: int(float(x)), example[1:-1].split(',') )

>>> lat = 150
>>> lon = 33
```

Comment: Perfect ilyankou :D

Comment: Will this work for creating too lists of each lat and lon values?

Comment: This little snippet works for a single row. I am not sure what your initial structure of all coordinates is (a long string separated by \n? a list? a dataframe?), but you should be able to write a loop and apply this to each row.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsup Michael. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. This script takes your input string and separates the assumed data points into separate list and converts them to floats.

```
'''Beaufuh 
Follow me on twitter @Beaufuhh
'''

#given data
location = '''(150. 90173422372985, -33. 668617545658414) 
(150.90125083937394,-33.6680017272324) 
(150.8952219040607,-33.69772659617821)
(150. 8495268692736, -33. 63824270203117) 
(150. 8940727 4513587, -33. 70546707 420955) 
(150. 8941156604801, -33. 70485201015482) 
(150. 89314185096964, -33. 714339905449854) 
(150.84348234362048,-33.63098091448995)
(150.8488030081157,-33.63777549474839)
(150. 837384089968, -33. 6256979266494 7)
(150. 958490613542, -33. 716626620381064)
(150. 89336724034592, -33. 712682761283325) 
(150.92057699351656,-33.68832356765278)
(150.92020399882543,-33.687884523564655) 
(150. 89387233383104, -33. 70732890445153) 
(150.83819855949918,-33.62531118563714) 
(150. 843766490138, -33. 631440326602785) 
(150.83880163743237,-33.626027838358304) '''
#create a list from location string and separate by new line
locations = location.split('\n')
#initialize list to hold longitudes and latitudes
longitudes = []
latitudes = []
#list iteration
for i in locations:
    #split each line by comma to seperate long and lat.
    i_split_by_comma = i.split(',')
    #list iteration
    for j in i_split_by_comma:
        #check if longitude
        if '(' in j:
            #replace paren
            j = j.replace('(', '')
            #replace space after decimal
            j = j.replace(' ','')
            #convert to float
            j = float(j)
            #append to new list
            longitudes.append(j)
        elif ')' in j:
            #replace paren
            j = j.replace(')', '')
            #replace space after decimal
            j = j.replace(' ','')
            #convert to float
            j = float(j)
            #append to new list
            latitudes.append(j)
        else:
            print('Something funky here. Inspection needed.')
#print new lists
print(longitudes, '\n\n\n\n', latitudes)
```